# Rails API authentication - sanity check and advise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, devise, csrf

I want to create a Rails application which exposes an API to be consumed by only authorised client applications (will be mobile apps for iOS / android). I've not started working on the app yet, but the primary method of accessing the underlying data will be through the api. I've been looking at using the [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) gem, but would need to add an authentication layer to it. I was thinking about using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and adding another model for storing client details, api key and secret key. Upon sign in through the api, the api key and secret are returned. The API key is transmitted with each request, but the secret key is not. Instead, it is used to sign each request; the request parameters are ordered by name, hashed using the secret key as the hash key. This signature is then added as a parameter to the request.

Does this system of authentication sound logical and secure?

I tried to prototype the system earlier, but ran into difficulty signing up a user using JSON with devise. At first I was getting a CSRF error. I then turned off protect_from_forgery and was getting another error. Is it safe to turn this off if I am authenticating in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`protect_from_forgery` helps you protect your HTML forms. If you're consuming JSON from mobile clients, you don't need it.

Here's what I would do if I were you:

- on user's account page, have a button that says "(re)generate API key"
- client then embeds this key into his calling code and passes with each request.
- your API server checks whether this API key can be used with this client id.

Very easy to implement and serves well.

Signing parameters also works and I used it in several projects with success. But it increases code complexity without any real gain (secret key is on the client, attacker already knows it).

Comment: Without signing, anyone in the middle of the client and the server can sniff the key. Therefore just passing an API key in clear text is not sufficient. I would rather the attacker have to disassemble my mobile app to get the key than be able to grab it out of the request.

Comment: @ctcherry: that's true. However, if your app is worth hacking, they will do it anyway. I personally see very little difference.

Comment: My applications aren't worth hacking to most people, but in my opinion as developers it's our responsibility to do our best to protect users with the best (reasonable) practices. It's the same reason I don't store passwords in plain text, even if most crackers wouldn't be interested in getting them anyway.

Comment: @ctcherry: it's about costs and profits. Several BIG sites that I know use exactly this approach, simple api key passing, no signature. It's simple and it provides some protection. Signing probably is not worth it (for them).

Comment: I guess we can agree to disagree :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can turn off rails CSRF protection since you are using a different authenticity method as long as a date or timestamp is always inside the parameters that are being signed. You can use this to compare the request time to the server time and make sure you aren't undergoing a replay attack.